# To select youngest australian person in an event

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to select the youngest australian person in an event where the person.age and countryname are in different tables.

Here is my solution. But it returned to an empty row[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJKA.png)

```
SELECT AthleteName, Age
FROM Athletes
JOIN Countries ON Countries.CountryID = Athletes.CountryID
WHERE CountryName = 'Australia'
AND Age = (SELECT MIN(Age) FROM Athletes)
```

Comment: That’s because you are selecting the minimum age of all athletes, not just Australian athletes

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What if two athletes have the same minimum age in an event? Where is the event in your query? So far we only see athletes and countries, no events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that the subquery `(SELECT MIN(Age) FROM Athletes)` will always return the minimum age among all athletes, regardless of their country. The query below should function correctly.

```sql
SELECT AthleteName, Age
FROM Athletes
JOIN Countries ON Countries.CountryID = Athletes.CountryID
WHERE CountryName = 'Australia'
AND Age = (SELECT MIN(Age) FROM Athletes WHERE CountryID = Countries.CountryID);
```